# Delete line after reading from text file

Tags: text, vbscript

How do I get this script to delete each line of text after reading it instead of just going onto the next one and still leaving it in the text file.

What can I do to change it?

```
Dim fso  
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = """UPS"" <User@Example.com>"
objEmail.Subject = "This is a test"

Const ForReading=1
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\UPS-Email.htm",ForReading).ReadAll
objEmail.HtmlBody = BodyText

'objEmail.AddAttachment "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\e.txt", 1)
row = 0
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    line = file.Readline
    dict.Add row, line
    row = row + 1
    objEmail.To = line

    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1"
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    objEmail.Send
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete content from a file while you're reading the file. What you can do is truncate the file after you finished reading from it:

```
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
    ...
Loop
file.Close

fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\e.txt", 2).Close
```

Comment: It only reads the first line then it deletes everything else.
How can I fix this.

Comment: If it does you didn't put the `fso.OpenTextFile("...", 2).Close` statement *after* the loop as I told you. Please follow instructions.

Comment: So like this.
`Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\e.txt", 1)
 row = 0
 Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
 line = file.Readline
 dict.Add row, line
 row = row + 1
 objEmail.To = line 
 ...
Loop
file.Close
fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\e.txt", 2).Close`

Comment: Yes. Like I wrote in my answer.